# Convert Switch to Object

Tags: javascript

I have this code:

```
var params = Spry.Utils.getLocationParamsAsObject();
theLeague = params.league;
switch (theLeague)
{
case 'boyswinter':
    var Soccer = new Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels("Soccer", {defaultTab: 0}); 
  break;
case 'girlswinter':
    var Soccer = new Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels("Soccer", {defaultTab: 1}); 
  break;
default:
    var Soccer = new Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels("Soccer", {defaultTab: 0}); 
}
```

I'd like to use an alternative to switch, and I found this bit of code to use as a guide:

```
var whatToBring = {
    "Sunny" : "Sunscreen and hat",
    "Rain" : "Umbrella and boots",
    "Cold" : "Scarf and Gloves",
    "Default" : "Play it by ear"
}
var gear = whatToBring[weather] || whatToBring["Default"];
```

However, I can't figure out how to swap in my stuff so that it works. It should be easy, but as a JS beginner, I can't wrap my head around it. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if using an object is the best method here, but in any event, this should work.

```
var leagueMap = {
    "boyswinter" : function(){ return new Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels("Soccer", {defaultTab: 0}); },
    "girlswinter" : function(){ return new Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels("Soccer", {defaultTab: 1}); },
    "Default" : function(){ return new Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels("Soccer", {defaultTab: 0}); }
}
var Soccer = (leagueMap[theLeague] || leagueMap["Default"])();
```

Comment: Thank you all. This solution did the trick. I'd be lying if I said I knew exactly what was going on here, or, like BBonifield said, if this is the best way to go about it, but it got the job done.

Comment: Ask another question about what's going on here if you want to find out more. =)

Answer (score 0):

Translating from your example it would be something like this:

```
var SoccerFactory = {
    'boyswinter' : new Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels("Soccer", {defaultTab: 0}),
    'girlswinter' : new Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels("Soccer", {defaultTab: 1}),
    'default' : new Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels("Soccer", {defaultTab: 0})
};

var Soccer = SoccerFactory[theLeague] || SoccerFactory['default'];
```

Please let me know if you'd like further explantation of the concepts used. I'm unsure about which parts you are having trouble understanding.

**Edit**

Or even better!

```
var SoccerFactory = {
    'boyswinter' : new Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels("Soccer", {defaultTab: 0}),
    'girlswinter' : new Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels("Soccer", {defaultTab: 1}),
    'default' : this['boyswinter']
};

var Soccer = SoccerFactory[theLeague] || SoccerFactory['default'];
```

Repeating yourself is bad. =)

Comment: This creates unneeded objects.  I'd suggest wrapping the creation blocks in lambda functions.

Comment: Yes you are right. I was just wondering why BlackTigerX was doing it this way and it hit me as soon as you posted your answer.

Answer (score 0):

should be something like:

```
var theLeague = {
    "boyswinter" : function() { return new Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels("Soccer", {defaultTab: 0}); },
    "girlswinter" : function() { return new Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels("Soccer", {defaultTab: 1}); },
    "Default" : function() { return new Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels("Soccer", {defaultTab: 0}); },
}
var l = theLeague[league] || theLeague["Default"];
```

Comment: Marc, note my comment on your post.  That's why.